# Return a specific element in a list - LISP

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, element

I'm trying to write a function called: get-element (board coords) that takes a board and a pair of coords representing a board position as input. The first element of the pair represents the column number and the second represents the row number (indexing starts from 0). The function returns the contents of that board position, which can be either X, O or NIL. Using the following test board state.

```
    (defparameter *test-board*
        '((nil nil nil nil nil nil)
          (O   nil nil nil nil nil)
          (X   nil nil nil nil nil)
          (X   X   O   nil nil nil)
          (O   O   X   nil nil nil)
          (nil nil nil nil nil nil)
          (nil nil nil nil nil nil)))
```

The function should work like so:

```
(get-element *test-board* ‘(0 0))
> NIL
```

I can't seem to understand the process to gain such as output. So far my code is as follows (But this is seriously wrong!):

```
  (col(nth 0 coords))
  (row(nth 1 coords)))
```

Any help with understanding how to retrieve specific elements within a list would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I will not give you the exact solution, but a reasoning that I hope will be useful to produce it by yourself.

Your data structure consists of a list, each element of which represent a row of the board. So you have a list with a number of elements equal to the number of rows of the board.

The elements of such list are themselves lists: so each row is represented by a list, in which each element represents a particular cell of the board (not a column, a cell!). So, your data structure is a list of lists.

So, one could ask: what is a column of the board in this representation? And the answer is: there is no actual data structure that can be called the column of the board, simply a column can be abastractly seen as: "all the elements at the same position of the internal lists".

So, if you want to extract a particular cell from your board representation, identified by a couple of coordinates (row number, column number), you must “translate” this information to your specific representation of the data structure, which is expressed instead in list of lists. For instance, if you want to get the content of the cell at the coordinates (3, 5), that is row 3 and column 5, you should reason in this way: I can access directly to the row 3, since it is the fourth element of the “big” list, but not to the column 5, since there is nothing immediately corresponding ot it.

But if I can access to row 3, for instance with `(nth 3 board)`, what I obtain is the list corresponding to the cells of such row, so there is no need to get column 5, I can just take element 5 of this list and I will get the content of the cell with coordinate (3, 5). So, it is sufficient to get the element number 5 of this list, for instance with `(nth 5 (nth 3 board))` (that is, since `(nth 3 board)` returns the list of cells of that row, you select the element 5 from that list).

I hope this can be useful to understand how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun get-element (list-of-list coord)
  "Return value of field in list-of-list."
  (let ((row (nth (first coord) list-of-list)))
    (nth (second coord) row)))
```

```
(defparameter *test-board*
     '((nil nil nil nil nil nil)
       (O   nil nil nil nil nil)
       (X   nil nil nil nil nil)
       (X   X   O   nil nil nil)
       (O   O   X   nil nil nil)
       (nil nil nil nil nil nil)
       (nil nil nil nil nil nil)))

(get-element *test-board* '(0 0)) ;; NIL
(get-element *test-board* '(1 0)) ;; O
(get-element *test-board* '(4 2)) ;; X
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will numerically select from a nested list, to any depth:

```
(defun nested-list-coord-select (nested-list coords)
  (loop for coord in coords
        with current = nested-list
        do (setf current (nth coord current))
        finally (return current)))

[1]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a a)) '(0 0))
A
[2]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a a)) '(0 1))
A
[3]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b)) '(0 1))
B
[4]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b (c d))) '(0 1))
B
[5]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b (c d))) '(0 2))
(C D)
[6]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b (c d))) '(0 2 0))
C
[7]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b (c d))) '(0 2 1))
D
[8]> (nested-list-coord-select '((a b (c d))) '(0 2 1 3))

*** - NTH: D is not a list
[9]> (nested-list-coord-select nil nil)
NIL
[10]> (nested-list-coord-select 42 nil)
42
```

If we replace `nth` using `elt` (remembering to reverse the arguments), then it becomes more generic. We can have a vector of lists of strings, and such.

Remark: ANSI Common Lisp has N-dimensional arrays, you know.